# Debugging micropython code using raspberrypi pico debug probe

Tags: micropython, debug

I was wondering if there is a way to debug micropython code on raspberrypi pico with/without the **"[debug probe](https://www.raspberrypi.com/documentation/microcontrollers/debug-probe.html)"**. Documentations described steps for C language in details, but nothing was said about micropython. Of course there's always the "print" option but I was looking for a solution to put some breakpoints in code and other debugging tools.

Comment: If you are running micropython from Thonny, click on MicroPython at botton of screen, then click on Configure interpreter. Look at the debug tab.